# Why I have to pass Bundle to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, parameter-passing, bundle, getter-setter

We usually use below style when we pass parameter to the fragment

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    String myVariable = "My variable string";
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("myVariable", myVariable);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

What happens when we use getter setter method:

```
private String myVariable;
public String getMyVariable() {
    return myVariable;
}
public void setMyVariable(String myVariable) {
    this.myVariable = myVariable;
}
public static MyFragment newInstance() {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    String passVariable = "My variable string";
    fragment.setMyVariable(passVariable);
    return fragment;
}


public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String passVariable = getMyVariable();

}
```

When I test with the second way, there is no problem occurs. So why we have to use the first way?

I also saw the post "[Why use bundle to pass data to fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765613/why-use-bundle-to-pass-data-to-fragment)". They said "it's easier for the system to restore its values when the fragment is re-instantiated" 
But I tested in case the fragment is popped from stack, the variable is still remained.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37765613/6950238) question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the framework needs to recreate your fragment, the data you have set with your second setter method is lost.

Argument bundles persist to recreated fragments.

Comment: Does the variable always loses or it will be loss sometimes? I tested in case the fragment is popped from stack, the variable is still remained.

Comment: It is lost when the fragment is recreated. One common source for recreation is device orientation changes.

Comment: Oh Thank you. I missed this case